# Is it good to return a Abstract class from a Interface

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a interface called `ABC`. I also have an abstract class `PQR` and there are 3 classes which extend this abstract class.

For example:

```
abstract class PQR {
    //...
}

interface ABC {
    //other methods....
    PQR returnRightClass();
}

class X extends PQR {
}

class Y extends PQR {
}

class Z extends PQR {
}
```

Now there are classes which implement the `ABC` interface. So what should I do to get the right class from X, Y, and Z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with returning an abstract class, though it is recommended to use interfaces as much as possible. If you can make `PQR` an interface, then do so. But if not, no worry.

> Now there are classes which implements ABC interface. So what
>   should I do to get the right class from x ,y ,z?

Just make sure each implementation of `returnRightClass()` in each class implementing `ABC` returns a proper instance of `PQR` (x,y or z).

**EDIT**

To answer your question:

```
public MyClassX implements ABC {

    public PQR returnRightClass() {
        return new x();
    }

}
```

Or

```
public MyClassY implements ABC {

    public PQR returnRightClass() {
        return new y();
    }

}
```

Or

```
public MyClassZ implements ABC {

    public PQR returnRightClass() {
        return new z();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just make sure each implementation of returnRightClass() in each class implementing ABC returns the proper a instance of PQR (x,y or z).and how can i do that

Answer (score 2):

You can return an abstract class. There's no law about returning interfaces or abstract classes, it depends on your software design:

One way to to return your `x`, `y`, `z` is to use the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_object).

Example (pseudocode):

```
public class PQRFactory {

    public PQR getPQR(condition) {

        switch (condition) {
            case condition_x :
                return new x();
            break;

            case condition_y :
                return new y();
            break;

            case condition_z :
                return new z();
            break;

            default : return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `condition` then you can use a [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to do what @JVerstry posted.

When your classes implement `ABC` interface, you can use the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to pass the factory to be used by the `ABC` implementors.

Example (pseudocode):

```
public abstract class AbstractABC implements ABC {

    protected PQRFactory factory;

    protected AbstractABC() {
        factory = new PQRFactory();
    }

    protected AbstractABC(PQRFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

}

public class ABCImpl1 extends AbstractABC() {

    //Override constructors needed to construct this class
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Its good to use `abstract` or `interface` for `return` value.

you can use `instanceof` operator for type matching.

like in some cases

```
PQR myObj = new z();

(myObj instanceof z) // returns true
(myObj instanceof x) // returns false
(myObj instanceof y) // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your design idea behind that, but wouldn't it just be easier to have your X,Y,Z, classes implement the interface itself? You still could put any common code in your abstract class that the three can derive from. In general I think is it better to reference interfaces then Abstract classes, in case you want to adjust it in the future. Just a thought.

Comment: It would be better to clarify what you mean by "in case you want to adjust it in the future."